# Usual field as foreign key

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have two tables. I want to make between them relationship, but the thing is that the child table connects to an attribute in a parent node, which is not a PK. How can I assign a non-PK field as a FK for a table?
Here are the tables. User Information:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class userinformation implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)    
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private int uID;

    @Column(name="LIB_ID")
    private String libID;

    //Other attributes
}
```

Lib Information

```
@Entity
@Table(name="libinfo")
public class Auth {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="AUTH_ID")
    private int authID;

    @Column(name="LIB_ID")
    private String lib_ID;

    //Other attributes
}
```

They both should be linked through `libID` (surely unique). Any idea how to implement it correctly?

Comment: You implement it "correctly" by using O-O techniques and putting an object reference rather than some arbitrary String. Then you get referential integrity. With standard JPA you cannot do what you are asking.

Comment: @NeilStockton but if I simply declare it as `private userinformation lib_ID`, how can I make sure that it links to the `libID` in the `userinformation` class

Comment: Firstly you wouldn't call some UserInformation field "lib_ID" ... it is the UserInformation OBJECT. Secondly you assign the field object, and post the code where you are persisting it. The Auth class will have a table which has a FK column across to UserInformation

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
class User {
  @Column(name = "lib_id")
  private String libID;
}
```

you must map the `Auth` entity as:

```
class Auth {
  @JoinColumn(name = "lib_id", referencedColumnName = "lib_id")
  @ManyToOne
  private User user;
}
```

Basically, `referencedColumnName` is used to inform the JPA provider that it should use a column other than the primary key column of the referenced entity (which is used by default with `@ManyToOne` mappings).

Comment: JPA spec _Applications that use referencedColumnName that is not primary key column(s) are not portable_

Comment: The JPA spec uses the phrase `not portable` in about 100 places, in different contexts. In the context of the `refrencedColumnName` attribute, it is used to clarify that JPA providers are not required to implement this attribute and hence applications may not be portable between providers. Given that associations using non-primary-key columns are a common database design practice, all three JPA 2.1 implementations supporting `refrencedColumnName` and the next version nowhere in sight, I wouldn't worry about an application using it not being portable.